# Strings and file

Tags: python, string

Suppose this is my list of languages.

```
aList = ['Python','C','C++','Java']
```

How can i write to a file like :

```
Python      : ...
C           : ...
C++         : ...
Java        : ...
```

I have used rjust() to achieve this. Without it how can i do ?

Here i have done manually. I want to **avoid** that,ie; it shuould be **ordered automatically**.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with [string formatting](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/typesseq-strings.html) operators

```
f=open('filename.txt','w')
for item in aList:
    print >>f, "%-20s : ..." % item
```

The 20 is the field width, while the "-" indicates to left justify it.

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean this?

```
>>> languages = ['Python','C','C++','Java']
>>> f = open('myfile.txt', 'w')
>>> print('\n'.join('%-10s: ...' % l for l in languages), file=f)
>>> f.close()
>>> print(open('myfile.txt').read())
Python    : ...
C         : ...
C++       : ...
Java      : ...
```

This uses the [format specification mini language](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language). Note the [print](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#print) statement uses 3.0 syntax. (Yeah I changed this since [Brian's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891895/strings-and-file/891897#891897) answer links to the 2.5.2 docs. Just for contrast.)

Answer (score 0):

Automatically determine colon position (using max width) and language order (sorted alphabetically):

```
languages = ['Python','C','C++','Java']
maxlen = max(map(len, languages))
with open('langs.txt', 'w') as f:
    for L in sorted(languages):
        f.write('%-*s: ...\n'% (maxlen, L)) 

print open('langs.txt').read()
```

Output:

```
C     : ...
C++   : ...
Java  : ...
Python: ...
```